# handle NoConnectionError with volley library not work

Tags: android, http

i'am learn volley library, but when i'm handle NoConnectionError is not work.

```
if( error instanceof NetworkError) {
    } else if( error instanceof ClientError) { 
    } else if( error instanceof ServerError) {
    } else if( error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
    } else if( error instanceof ParseError) {
    } else if( error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
    noconnection();
    } else if( error instanceof TimeoutError) {
timeout();                  
    }
```

if not connection  noconnection(); not work, how solve it ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the order of your if statements. Put `NoConnectionError` first and it should work. Basically `NetworkError` encompasses `NoConnectionError`.

```
if( error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
    } else if( error instanceof ClientError) { 
    } else if( error instanceof ServerError) {
    } else if( error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
    } else if( error instanceof ParseError) {
    } else if( error instanceof NetworkError) {
    } else if( error instanceof TimeoutError) {                
}
```